# Stack Overflow etiquette regarding old posts

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, etiquette

Scenario: You discover more information in relation to a Stack Overflow post that would be useful to the community in answering your question.  However, you wrote the question several days ago and it is no longer receiving additional views.

Is it poor etiquette to create a new post?

Comment: i believe that this should be posted in meta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have something to add to your question, edit it and add the new information. That will "bump" the question and it will likely begin to receive more views.

Comment: Also, if you're afraid people may have seen your question before and thought it wasn't interesting, try changing the title as well in your edit

Comment: I wasn't aware of the "bumping."  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 4):

Editing your question will "bump" it so that people will see it again, so just go ahead and edit it.  If you still aren't garnering enough views then add a bounty.  Please don't create a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

It is not poor etiquette. If you are able to post a more well-defined question, delete your old question (assuming it has no answers) and post a new one. I may get flamed for this, but it provides experts with the "enhanced" ability to see a better question and have an opportunity to answer it. I believe it's good for the community.

Comment: Why not just update your existing question with the new info?  What if your old question does have answers?

Comment: Why not delete the post and add another?

Comment: Because you are given a mechanism to add new information about your question.  Again: What if your old question does have answers?

Comment: You are given a mechanism to delete a question and ask it again too.  Your logic applies equally for your argument and against it.

Comment: @hamlin11: Because deleted questions still exist. Sure, the old revisions of questions also still exist, but they're inexorably associated with the *new* version of the question. Everyone can see what you did, and everyone can understand why you changed it. Delete+re-ask sounds shady, like you're hiding something.